# Matplotlib: pcolormesh or pcolor from 3 columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a file 'mydata.tmp' which contains 3 colums like this:

```
3.81107 0.624698 0.000331622 
3.86505 0.624698 0.000131237 
3.91903 0.624698 5.15136e-05 
3.97301 0.624698 1.93627e-05 
1.32802 0.874721 1.59245 
1.382   0.874721 0 
1.43598 0.874721 0 
1.48996 0.874721 4.27933
```

etc.

Then I want to make a heatmap color plot  where the first two columns are coordinates, and the third column are the values of that coordinates.

Also, I would like to set the third column in log scale.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following code using a scatter type of plot

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('mydata.tmp', delim_whitespace=True, 
                     comment='#',header=None,
                     names=['a','b','c'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.scatter(df.a, df.b, c=df.c,  cmap="GnBu", s=400, 
     norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())

fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

and I get the picture I show below (Ignore the scale of the x axis). However I want to get the result I achieve when I do it whit GNUplot with this code (I also attach the GNUplot Image)

```
plot mydata.tmp using 1:2:3 with image
```

Maybe I have to use pcolormesh?
Thank you!

GNUplot Image:
[image: GNUplot Image]

Matplotlib Image:
[image: Matplotlib Image]

When I try Khalil code I get this Image:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the image from the GNUplot into your question?

Comment: I have done it now! thanks

Comment: You wanted `pcolormesh` I think

Comment: I have edited my question with some improvements now. How Can I implement pcolormesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Tested and working on some data I have.
Spacing is very important. set it according the gridding you want for the plot. The higher the spacing the smoother THE image is but longer calculation.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# import data
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.tmp', delim_whitespace=True, 
                     comment='#',header=None,
                     names=['1','2','3'])

x = df['1']
y = df['2']
z = df['3']

# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points

spacing = 500
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), spacing), np.linspace(y.min(), 
                     y.max(), spacing)

XI, YI = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

# Interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')

ZI = rbf(XI, YI)

#plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sc = ax.imshow(ZI, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
            extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), 
                    y.max()], cmap="GnBu", norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=ZI.min(),
                    vmax=ZI.max()))

fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax, fraction=0.05, pad=0.01)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have edited some improvments in my code. When I try your code, I get this error: 
    numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: could you try! i do not have your data!!

Comment: When I try it I get this error: ValueError: Unknown interpolation method array([1.32802   , 1.38199939, 1.43597878, 1.48995816, 1.54393755,
       (...)
       1.86781388, 1.92179327, 1.97577265, 2.02975204, 2.08373143,
        3.91903061, 3.97301   ]) for 1 dimensional data

Comment: Thank you, it is better now! But, when I try to insert  norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm() in imshow to get the colorbar at logscale as before, I get:   raise ValueError("values must all be positive")
ValueError: values must all be positive

Comment: Sorry, this is the error I get:     return vmin * np.ma.power((vmax / vmin), val)
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero.  raise ValueError("values must all be positive")

Comment: Try removing `, norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max())`. it is working fine with real data I have.

Comment: Yes, It works, the thing is that I need a logscale in the colorbar (z variable). And I have problems with zeros values when I use  matplotlib.colors.LogNorm in imshow

Comment: use `norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=ZI.min(),vmax=ZI.max())` instead and check if it throws any error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179215/discussion-between-laura-and-khalil-al-hooti).